# WSO2 Proxy Service URL not working with SOAPUI

Tags: apache-axis, wso2, soapui, wso2-esb

We have CXF based SOAP web services and we are hitting these services from SOAP UI with no problem. With one of these services, I setup a ProxyService on barebone WSO2 ESB 4.6.0. The proxy service seems to be working with the "Try It" option from the admin console. When I try to access it from SOAPUI, the WSO2 ESB starts complaining that

"The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/HelloWorldProxyService and the WSA Action = . If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator."

Now, when I change the endpoint URL in SOAPUI as http:// hostname:8280/services/service-name.port-name/operation-name things start to work.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Are there configuration options on the WSO2 ESB which will let us use traditional SOAPUI with WSO2 ESB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can point the proxy service url(you can view this, via service dashboard of the particular proxy) in soapui and for the "action", in the insequence of the proxy define a property call;
. header name="Action" value="soap action"

Here is the guide on vailable properties

http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/3.0.0/docs/properties_guide.html

Comment: This solves the problem. However we will have to change all of our SOAPUI scripts to add the header which can be derived from the SOAP envelop. Is there a way for WSO2 to derive this information directly from the SOAP envelop?

Comment: Im not sure how is your request looks like. Normally, in the axis2 configuration we define several levels of dispatcher. You can check that in your axis2 configuartion file. In the "Inflow" dispatch phase, you will see URIBasedDispatcher,SOAPActionBasedDispatcher,RequestURIOperationDispatcher,SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher. These are used to dispatch the message to the corrcet endpoint. If you define the "soapaction" servers will use that to dispatch, else if you define the operation in the URI, it will be used. Or else messagebode based dispatch. If none of them present the message will fail

Comment: Clearly my SOAPUI request has information on which service and what operation to call. When I connect directly to my app server, the CXF engine on app server figures out what class to invoke into. It seems like AXIS2 inside the WSO2 ESB is not able to figure out the operation from the SOAP request. From the list of dispatchers that you are naming out, SoapMessageBodyBasedDispatcher should do this job but somehow its not doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem if I put `operation1` at the end of `WS URI` (http://somedomain.com/WebServiceProxyName/operation1), but post a SOAP message body with constructs for another operation(operation2,3,4,5...) it works!!!

**Sample**

```
POST http://somedomain.com/..../operation1 HTTP/1.1
....
....
<soap:Envelope ...>
<soap:Header/>
  <soap:Body>
     <ws:operation2>



     </ws:operation2>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the (original) WSDL and put the soapAction there:

You can define it as an attribute of the http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/:operation element in the binding section, e.g.

```
<wsdl:binding name="healthcheck-1.0.0SOAP" type="tns:HealthCheck100PortType">
  <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="doHealthCheck">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.xyz.ch/healthcheck-1.0.0/doHealthCheck"/>
```